# ABAddressBook get View for one contact

Tags: ios4, abaddressbook

I use a custom UITableView to display some data together with the contacts out of the users address book. I won't to invoke the standard, non-editing, view of a single contact when one this entries is tapped. How do I do that? I mean I know how to figure out wether a contact or one of my custom entries was tapped but how can I invoke this view?

Thanks.
Philip

Comment: You know the tapped person by means of a returned reference from the people picker and want to present the details view later on?

Comment: Right. I got the names from a abaddressbook array copy. In my NSObject I store the information I need for my TableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the exact problem is that you have because it lacks detailed information.

But perhaps all you want is to push a ABPersonViewController instance initialized with the selected person on your navigation controller.

Comment: Exakt that is what I want to do! Thanks!